# How to open a batch on a new window from a python script

Tags: python, loops, batch-file

I'm trying to create a monitoring script for a specific process that will run in a loop but I don't know how to make the app batch run on a new window without affecting the monitoring script.

This is what I have so far, but it runs on the same cmd window. Also, how can I make this a simple look so when it can check every half hour if the process is running and if it's not, execute the the app batch file.

This is what I have so far, but everything I find online is way over my head...

```
    import subprocess

def process_exists(process_name):
    call = 'TASKLIST', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % process_name
    # use buildin check_output right away
    output = subprocess.check_output(call).decode()
    # check in last line for process name
    last_line = output.strip().split('\r\n')[-1]
    # because Fail message could be translated
    return last_line.lower().startswith(process_name.lower())

print (process_exists('process.exe'))

if not process_exists('process.exe'):
    subprocess.call([r'app.bat'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that one might use:

[1] **Threading**:

```
import threading
def main_runner():
    # some code
    return

every_n_mins = 1
threading.Timer( 60*every_n_mins, main_runner, [loop_number, every_n_mins] ).start()
```

[2] **for loop**:
Just add a `for loop` with `sleep` in the code.

[3] **Task Scheduler**:
use a `task scheduler` in the operating system to keep running the code at specified periods. In windows it is calle dtask scheduler.

Each method has its merits and open for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Just found something that worked, at least for the new window issue. Just removed the brackets and added the following to subprocess.call:

```
subprocess.call('app.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the loop, just thought I'd mention it here for the super beginners like myself:

This is the final script:

```
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

def process_exists(process_name):
    call = 'TASKLIST', '/FI', 'imagename eq %s' % process_name
    # use buildin check_output right away
    output = subprocess.check_output(call).decode()
    # check in last line for process name
    last_line = output.strip().split('\r\n')[-1]
    # because Fail message could be translated
    return last_line.lower().startswith(process_name.lower())

print (process_exists('ethminer.exe'))

x=1
while x == 1:
    if not process_exists('ethminer.exe'):
         #subprocess.call(r'', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
         subprocess.call(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\ethminer-0.19.0-alpha.0-cuda10.0-windows-amd64\bin\main.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
         print(datetime.now())
         time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: if you do this `x==1` then there will be no condition that will stop the loop. (You may or may not want this feature).